# magento login from external site, across domains

Tags: php, magento, authentication, cookies, single-sign-on

I am trying to link up a web application with magento, so that when a user logs onto the web application, he/she would also be automatically logged onto magento.

To make it simpler, I am testing it out with a simple log-in form. So now I have magento installed, a custom module with custom API written, and a PHP form that calls the log-in API to try to authentication the user.

code snippet for the API model:

```
class Modulename_Model_Api extends Mage_Api_Model_Resource_Abstract
{
    function login($email, $password)
    {
        Mage::app()->setCurrentStore("default");
        Mage::getSingleton('core/session'); 

        $session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');

        if($session->login($email, $password)) {
            return $session->getSessionId();
        } else {
            $this->_fault('login_fail');
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

code snippet for the PHP form:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {
    $proxy = new SoapClient('http://www.domain.com/magento/api/?wsdl');
    $sessionId = $proxy->login('apiuser', 'apikey');

    try {
        $token = $proxy->call($sessionId, 'customer.login', array(
            'email'=>$_POST['email'],
            'password'=>$_POST['password']
        ));
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->faultstring;
    }

    if ($token) {
        setcookie('frontend', $token, time()+3600, "/magento/", ".domain.com");
        header('Location: http://www.domain.com/magento/');
    } else {
        //some error handling
    }

}

?>

<form method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="email"/>
    <input type="password" name="password"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Login" />
</form>
```

So far, the log-in form works perfectly.
But when I try to put the PHP form onto another domain, it fails.

I could fetch the session ID from the API call. So my best guess would be something has gone wrong when I try to set the cookie with the session ID across the domains.

Could anyone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct. When setting a session cookie on the same domain as your Magento backend, Magento is able to read it and log you in. However when you try setting it from a different domain, your browser disallows it due to cross-domain cookie restrictions (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Privacy_and_third-party_cookies). If you are trying to log your customers in from a different domain, you should use Magento's OAuth API (http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/rest/introduction.html).

So, basically your webapp will act as the OAuth consumer and Magento will act as the OAuth provider. Anyone logging into your site will log into Magento first. After the OAuth dance is complete and your webapp gets the OAuth access token from Magento, you can use your own auth module to handle authentication/authorization using this access token.

Just to be clear, this solution will login customers first to Magento and then they will be "automatically" logged in to your site.